# Typescript function attribute inference

Tags: typescript

I try to make a strongly typed form generator and in order to configurate it, I need some options based on model. I would like to know if it's possible to infer return type of a fonction from it arguments, probably I missed some typescript basics on inference.

I made a simple, synthetic ( and useless ) example to illustrate my purpose:

```
// Option type that take for keys an OptionName and return fields based on Model 

type Options<Model extends Record<string, any>, OptionName extends string = string> = {
  [key in OptionName]: {
    fields: {
      [field in keyof Model]?: {
        label: string;
      };
    };
  };
};


// Here a basic function who return options and expect getting return type based on options

function useOptions<Model extends Record<string, any>>(options: Options<Model>): Options<Model, keyof typeof options> {
  return options as Options<Model, keyof typeof options>;
}
```

And something like that to use it:

```
type Person = {
  lastname: string;
  firstname: string;
  country: string;
};

const options: Options<Person> = {
  ContactFields: {
    fields: {
      lastname: {
        label: 'Lastname',
      },
      firstname: {
        label: 'Firstname',
      },
    },
  },
  AddressFields: {
    fields: {
      country: {
        label: 'Country',
      },
    },
  },
};


// Does not return type error 
const { ContactFields, AddressFields } = useOptions<Person>(options);

// Does not return type error
// Should return type errors since return didn't match options
const { OptionOne, OptionTwo } = useOptions<Person>(options);
```

I expect this as return type:

```
type ExpectedReturnType = {
  ContactFields: {
    fields: {
      [key in keyof Person]?: {
        label: string;
      };
    };
  };
  AddressFields: {
    fields: {
      [key in keyof Person]?: {
        label: string;
      };
    };
  };
};
```

Is something in typescript is possible in order to solve this ? or I may find an alternative ?

Thanks in advance for your answer :)

Comment: What type of return value do you expect from `useOptions<Person>(options)` ?

Comment: Hey thanks for your attention, i edit my question with it :)

Comment: Why this example `const { ContactFields, AddressFields } = useOptions<Person>(options);` should return type error?

Comment: Oh my bad, misunderstanding... I try to say that I expect no type errors on this :p But on this ```const { OptionOne, OptionTwo } = useOptions<Person>(options);
```

Comment: In order to make it work, you should infer `options` argument. It means that you neither can use explicit type `Options<Person>` for `options` object  not explicit generic `Options` for `useOptions` function

Comment: I think it would be helpful to explain more clearly what you intend to do with the useOptions method. Why does it need to return the options? At the moment you could just write `const options = {...}` (without explicit typing) and then `const {optionOne, optionTwo} = options` would give you the desired error... (and of course you could use a generic parameter for useOptions to output the exact input type)

Comment: @captain-yossarian Sorry I don't think I get your point, did you have a small example ?

Comment: @Robin As I said it's a synthetic example without logic ;). In fact it return generated components base on name ( what I call OptionName here ) who contain JSX Inputs for each fields. The problem is that there is no way to check if the return type is trully correct and therefore it could make compilation trouble at use. But in order to make my example understable I made a lighter one, I can provide a clearer case if you need :).

Comment: 1) remove explicit type `Options<Person>` from `const options: Options<Person>`
2) remove `Person` from `useOptions<Person>`
And try to type once again your function using inference on function arguments

Answer (score 2):

Consider this example:

```js
// Option type that take for keys an OptionName and return fields based on Model 

type Options<Model extends Record<string, any>, OptionName extends string = string> = {
    [key in OptionName]: {
        fields: Partial<Record<keyof Model, { label: string }>>
    };
};


// Here a basic function who return options and expect getting return type based on options

function useOptions<Keys extends string, Model extends Record<string, any>,>(options: Options<Model, Keys>): Options<Model, Keys> {
    return options as Options<Model, keyof typeof options>;
}

type Person = {
    lastname: string;
    firstname: string;
    country: string;
};

const options = {
    ContactFields: {
        fields: {
            lastname: {
                label: 'Lastname',
            },
            firstname: {
                label: 'Firstname',
            },
        },
    },

};


const result = useOptions(options)
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NlgrOw)

If you want to infer return type - you need to infer input type.

In order to infer input time you need to get rid of explicit types from `const options` and explicit generic parameter in `useOptions<Person>`.

If you are interested in inference on function arguments you can check my [article](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments)

P.S. As you might have noticed I have added `Keys` generic argument to infer root keys of input parameter

---

Try to avoid using explicit generic parameters when you want to call your function. There are only two justified cases when you aare allowed to do it.

**First**
When you have an empty array:

```js
const handleArray = <T,>(arr: T[]) => arr

handleArray([]) // never []
handleArray<number>([]) // number[]
```

**Second**
When you have an api call:

```js
const handleApi = <T,>() => ({}) as T

handleApi<{ user: string }>() // {user: string}
```

Always try to infer your input parameters instead of explicitly declare them

Comment: Ok seems clear, so I can't have both inference from Options and a generic parameter in input ? ( In your example neither options nor useOptions are typed on Person ).

Comment: Yes, you can't have them both in this particular case

Comment: See this corresponding [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10571) for details.

Comment: @Robin thank you for the link, was not aware about hit issue

Comment: Thanks guys for your time and explanations :)